# tensorflow keras embedding lstm

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm, embedding

I would like to use the Embedding layer before feeding my input data into the LSTM network I am attempting to create.. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
input_step1 = Input(shape=(SEQ_LENGTH_STEP1, NR_FEATURES_STEP1), 
                           name='input_step1')

step1_lstm = CuDNNLSTM(50,
                       return_sequences=True,
                       return_state = True,
                       name="step1_lstm")

out_step1, state_h_step1, state_c_step1 = step1_lstm(input_step1)
```

I am a bit confused regarding how I am supposed to add an Embedding layer here..

Here is the description of the Embedding layer from the documentation:

```
keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim, 
                       output_dim, 
                       embeddings_initializer='uniform',
                       embeddings_regularizer=None, 
                       activity_regularizer=None, 
                       embeddings_constraint=None, 
                       mask_zero=False, 
                       input_length=None)
```

The confusing part is that my defined `Input` has a sequence length and number of features defined. Writing it here again:

```
input_step1 = Input(shape=(SEQ_LENGTH_STEP1, NR_FEATURES_STEP1), 
                           name='input_step1')
```

When defining an Embedding layer, I am pretty confused about which parameters of the `Embedding` function corresponds to "number of sequence" and "number of features in each time step". Can anyone guide me how I can integrate an Embedding layer to my code above?

**ADDENDUM:**

If I try the following:

```
SEQ_LENGTH_STEP1  = 5 
NR_FEATURES_STEP1 = 10 

input_step1 = Input(shape=(SEQ_LENGTH_STEP1, NR_FEATURES_STEP1), 
                           name='input_step1')

emb = Embedding(input_dim=NR_FEATURES_STEP1,
                output_dim=15,
                input_length=NR_FEATURES_STEP1)

input_step1_emb = emb(input_step1)

step1_lstm = CuDNNLSTM(50,
                       return_sequences=True,
                       return_state = True,
                       name="step1_lstm")

out_step1, state_h_step1, state_c_step1 = step1_lstm(input_step1_emb)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer step1_lstm is incompatible with the layer:
expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 5, 10, 15]
```

I am obviously not doing the right thing.. Is there a way to integrate `Embedding` into the LSTM network I am trying to attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Keras [Embedding](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/) documentation:

> **Arguments**
>
> - input_dim: int > 0. Size of the vocabulary, i.e. maximum integer index + 1.
> - output_dim: int >= 0. Dimension of the dense embedding.
> - input_length: Length of input sequences, when it is
>     constant. This argument is required if you are going to connect 
>     Flatten then Dense layers upstream (without it, the shape of the dense
>     outputs cannot be computed).

---

Therefore, from your description, I assume that:

- `input_dim` corresponds to the vocabulary size (number of distinct words) of your dataset. For example, the vocabulary size of the following dataset is 5:

  ```
  data = ["Come back Peter,",
          "Come back Paul"]
  ```
- `output_dim` is an arbitrary hyperparameter that indicates the dimension of your embedding space. In other words, if you set `output_dim=x`, each word in the sentence will be characterized with `x` features.
- `input_length` should be set to `SEQ_LENGTH_STEP1` (an integer indicating the length of each sentence), assuming that all the sentences have the same length.

The output shape of an embedding layer is `(batch_size, input_length, output_dim)`.

---

Further notes regarding the addendum:

- `team_in_step1` is undefined.
- Assuming that your first layer is an `Embedding` layer, the expected shape of the input tensor `input_step1` is `(batch_size, input_length)`:

  ```
  input_step1 = Input(shape=(SEQ_LENGTH_STEP1,), 
                             name='input_step1')
  ```

  Each integer in this tensor corresponds to a word.
- As mentioned above, the embedding layer could be instantiated as follows:

  ```
  emb = Embedding(input_dim=VOCAB_SIZE,
                  output_dim=15,
                  input_length=SEQ_LENGTH_STEP1)
  ```

  where `VOCAB_SIZE` is the size of your vocabulary.
- This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123481/how-to-build-a-language-model-using-lstm-that-assigns-probability-of-occurence-f/51126064#51126064) contains a reproducible example that you might find useful.

Comment: thank you very much for your clarification. I corrected the typo you mentioned above.