# Tensorflow: convert a `tf.data.Dataset` iterator to a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a dataset that comes in as a `tf.data.Dataset` from the new `tf.Datasets` module. Of course the `tf.data.Dataset` is an iterator over examples, but I need to actually convert this iterator into a full tensor containing all of the data loaded into memory. I am working with textual data and in order to extract the vocabulary of the corpus for Tokenization, I actually need the entire corpus of text at once.

I can of course write a loop to do this, but I was wondering if there was a more vectorized or faster way to implement the same task. Thanks.

I can at least provide the beginnings of the code. Note I am using Tensorflow 2.0a to try and get ready for the changeover:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

# Download the data
imdb_builder = tfds.builder('imdb_reviews')
imdb_builder.download_and_prepare()

# Setup training test split
imdb_train = imdb_builder.as_dataset(split=tfds.Split.TRAIN)
imdb_test = imdb_builder.as_dataset(split=tfds.Split.TEST)

# Look at the specs on the dataset if you wish
# print(imdb_builder.info)
```

To look at a single example. Observe that the data is un-tokenized.

```
a, = imdb_train.take(1)
print(a['text'])

tf.Tensor(b"As a lifelong fan of Dickens, I have ...", shape=(), dtype=string)
```

This is where I got stuck. Note that when trying to create the iterator over this dataset I obtained an error:

```
iter = imdb_train.batch(10).repeat(1).make_one_shot_iterator()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-35-1bf70c474a05> in <module>()
----> 1 imdb_train = imdb_train.batch(10).repeat(1).make_one_shot_iterator()

AttributeError: 'RepeatDataset' object has no attribute 'make_one_shot_iterator'
```

Comment: You don't need to load your whole corpus at once (and you really shouldn't). You could use `tf.data.Dataset` and `.map` with custom functor similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55421290/tensorflow-2-0-keras-how-to-write-image-summaries-for-tensorboard) (it's not like I'm plugging my answer there or anything, you know). `Tensorflow Datasets` library with it's [Tokenizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/features/text/Tokenizer) could be helpful here as well. Vocabulary gatherer should be quite fine to code with both those concepts.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke thanks for the comment. Yes, you picked up on of the frustrations here. So in order to extract the full vocabulary, I would need to iterate over the entire dataset--so that I know I obtained all possible words. Here is an example using Tokenizer--see the accepted answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123481/how-to-build-a-language-model-using-lstm-that-assigns-probability-of-occurence-f/51126064#51126064

Comment: This one is a different thing, I meant more modern and readable approach than the one you linked. And iterating via `map` as `tf.data.Dataset` is supposed to work. Although I'm really unsure whether `tensorflow` and it's `tf.data.Dataset` abstraction would be convenient to work with in the long run in the NLP case (e.g. lemmatizing). If I were you I would change the framework (if you can ofc). If you could provide me with sample `tf.data.Dataset` I might work something out though.

Comment: I added some code--at least as far as I got. The new Tensorflow Datasets don't seem to follow the `tf.data.Dataset` spec 100%, so for some reason I could not create the iterator. Not sure if this is a Tensorflow 2.0 issue or such? The idea is to iterate over this and identify the words and assign them to ids. There is a tf.lookup function for assigning a string to an id: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/lookup/StaticVocabularyTable

Comment: That's most succinct I can come up with in a reasonable amount of time. Was thinking about using `map` and pipelining this (and other) operations you might encounter along the way, but it seems `Tensorflow` doesn't really have the tools (tbh it's not focused on text processing).

Comment: Oh thanks so much @SzymonMaszke . Yeah, I generally work with images myself, but was trying to explore text a bit as well. Thanks so much for your effort. I can at least get started with what you were able to produce and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Data Loading

Using `tfds.load` is simpler and more compact:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

train = tfds.load("imdb_reviews", as_supervised=True, split=tfds.Split.TRAIN)
```

### 2. Vocabulary saver

Pretty simple, you may want to start indexing from zero.

```
class Tokenizer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vocab = {}
        self._counter: int = 1
        self.tokenizer = tfds.features.text.Tokenizer()

    def __call__(self, text):
        # Haven't found anything working with tf.tensor, oh sweet irony
        tokens = self.tokenizer.tokenize(text.numpy())
        for token in tokens:
            if not token in self.vocab:
                self.vocab[token] = self._counter
                self._counter += 1
```

TBH it's a shame there is no `tokenizer`-like utility for plain tensors and I need to convert them like that, but oh well, it's still in the alpha stage.

### 3. Tokenize your data

Since `TF2.0` and it's `eager` mode you can iterate with `one_shot_iterator` and other strange ideas comfortably using loop:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer()

for text, _ in train:
    tokenizer(text)
```

**Important:** You don't have to load everything into the memory as it's an iterator. Though you may encounter problems with memory in `vocab` for really large corpuses.

### 4. Results

Printing items and their indices:

```
print(list(tokenizer.vocab.keys())[:10])
print(list(tokenizer.vocab.values())[:10])
```

Gives us:

```
['This', 'was', 'soul', 'provoking', 'I', 'am', 'an', 'Iranian', 'and', 'living']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```